# UICollectionView don't update cell during pagination

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with horizontal paging enabled, each cell fill entire screen and contain a single `ImageView`.

What i want is to update both cell that engaged in pagination (If you turning from page 0 to 1 i want to update both of them in the middle of the way)

so i overrided below methods:

```
public func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
        var currentPage = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
        if (0.0 != fmodf(Float(currentPage), 1.0)) {
            currentPage += 1
        }

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: Int(currentPage), section: 0)
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
            return
        }

        // This cell is moving out of screen
        cell.image.isHidden = true

    }
```

and

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
        var currentPage = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
        if (0.0 != fmodf(Float(currentPage), 1.0)) {
            currentPage += 1
        }

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: IndexPath(row: Int(currentPage), section: 0)) as? MyCell else {
            return
        }
        // This cell entered the screen
        cell.image.isHidden = false
    }
```

The problem is that none of the change in image's hidden state wont take effect, if i print `cell.image.isHidden` it shows the correct state but the ui is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace every

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
        return
}
```

with

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as? MyCell else {
        return
}
```